# Prius 2004 (generation II): brake/ABS warning lights

Tags: brake-fluid, prius, brake-light

In a previous post I recounted how a brake issue was perturbing the hybrid battery.  After having the brake job done, a few weeks later (but not much driving in terms of miles), the (red) brake light and the (yellow) ABS light with the circled exclamation mark appeared on the dashboard.  They would appear upon starting the car, remain for a while, disappear, reappear, while driving.  Also, I noticed that the car was braking in a very weird (and non-reassuring) way, as if I had to apply more force to the pedal.  Also, upon starting the car, the car would start moving on its own a little bit (again, not reassuring) and, upon turning the car off, the brake pedal would move by itself.

I called the same shop and they said they would have to run an ABS test ($100+ dollars) and take it from there.

I looked online, thought for a while that it was the inverter coolant pump. I checked as shown [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XHe5dpHaFY4) and there were some bubbles.

Any hints as to what is going on?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not a question.

Comment: We welcome you to the site, but you need to realize Stack Exchange isn't a typical forum. We welcome your experiences, but it needs to follow the SE pattern of questions and answers. If you'd like to post your experience as a question, then post a separate item as an answer to the experience, by all means. Please read the [Tour](http://mechanics.stackexchange.com/tour) and [Help Pages](http://mechanics.stackexchange.com/help) to get a better understanding of how it works.

Comment: Ok, I reworded the question. Feel free to make edits as long as the information is intact. I already asked how I can edit my own question(s) in the other post. Please let me know. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I recently stumbled upon [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CIRhyzDhqnE) which shows that such a problem can be due to a low brake fluid level.  I went to check that, and it was low, although right above the “Min” level line.  I still went ahead and added more fluid.  Lo and behold, it worked, at least so far.

What is surprising to me is that the brake level is low rather than high, even though the brake pads were changed.  Perhaps they bled part of the fluid at the shop to “make room” for the thicker new pads and then forgot to top it off?  Or perhaps there is a small leak?